# Django Channels setting custom channel_name

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm using Django channels and I'm able to properly connect and send message with builtin channel_name provided.
I'm wondering if there is a way to change and register a custom channel_name within web socket connection. 
I tried changing it but channel_layer alredy stored builtin channel_name and I'm unable to send a message.

This is a provided test class

```py
class TestWebSocket(AsyncWebsocketConsumer): 
   async def connect(self):
        self.channel_name = "custom.channelname.UNIQUE"
        await self.accept()

   async def test_message(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': event['message']
        }))
```

Here how I send a message:

```py
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('custom.channelname.UNIQUE',
                                  {'type': 'test.message', 'message': 'dfdsdsf'})
```

I read documentation and it stores `channel_name` inside *db*, but each time I perform a connection, that name will change. I want to avoid flooding *db* with update calls.
So this is why I'm trying to force my own channel names.

There is a way to change it or is oly waste of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The channel name is deseided by your channel layer https://github.com/django/channels/blob/580499752a65bfe4338fe7d87c833dcd5d4a3939/channels/layers.py#L259 https://github.com/django/channels/blob/580499752a65bfe4338fe7d87c833dcd5d4a3939/channels/consumer.py#L46

so I would instead suggest using a `group` this you can setup with any name you like.

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#groups

```py
class TestWebSocket(AsyncWebsocketConsumer): 
   async def connect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            "custom.channelname.UNIQUE",
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.groups.append("custom.channelname.UNIQUE") # important otherwise some cleanup does not happened on disconnect.
        await self.accept()

   async def test_message(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': event['message']
        }))


# to send to that group
await channel_layer.group_send(
    "custom.channelname.UNIQUE",
    {"type": "test.message", "message":"Hello!"},
)
```

Comment: Indeed, I used a ```group``` to manage custom channel_names, now I can send a message to a selected user connected to that custom ```group```. This is a correct way to manage a such scenario. Didn't know that ```self.groups.append``` is needed for a correct cleanup

Comment: you don't need to do the `append` if you manually clean up in `websocket_disconect` but if you add it to the `groups` then the superclass will do that cleanup.